# Meteor - synchronizing meteor packages among developer's machines

Tags: meteor

I'm actually not doing this but planning to do it in the future.

I know that you can recreate a meteor project in another developer's PC by pushing it to github and checking the *.meteor* directory (although not the *local* sub directory). That way, when another developer clones it to her PC and do:

meteor npm install 
meteor run

Every package, meteor and npm, is going to be installed along with the **specific** version of meteor release (which is in *.meteor/release*).

Now, my question is: 
after adding, upgrading, removing some meteor packages and pushing .meteor directory changes to github, are other developer's meteor packages going to synchronize accordingly, after doing *meteor run*? I mean all his/her meteor packages are going to be added, upgraded, removed to be exactly as you originally did?

Is this the way to have the **exact meteor environment** (meteor packages) in every meteor developer's machine?

Many thanks for your help and bye ...

Comment: Have a look at file `.meteor/versions`

Comment: Hi @ghybs, thanks for replying. As I understand .meteor/version file has a record of the version of _every_ meteor package installed; be it primary or dependency (installed automatically from another package install). How can I use that file to be sure meteor packages from several developers are synchronized? ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I can see, meteor really synchronizes everything when it encounters changes in *.meteor* files, for example *packages* or *versions*.

So, the idea, as meteor experts say all the time, is to check this folder to github to, kind of, propagate the changes your project has received.

I don't know for sure if the meteor version is also synchronized in other PC's when meteor finds a new version in .meteor/release. For example, imagine you upgrade your version from 1.4 to 1.5. I suppose meteor will update this new version to *.meteor/release*. Then it is going to go to github repo and other programmers will pull the file. Then the question is: is meteor going to upgrade itself in response to this change? I suppose it will.

Thanks and bye ...

Comment: "is meteor going to upgrade itself" yes it will. It will also use an earlier version if specified so. This is typically what happens when you see "downloading meteor-tool…" when launching `meteor run`.

Comment: Excellent @ghybs; your statement completes everything about this issue of "cloning" meteor projects among a team of developers ...